# How do update a single cell of Scala Dataframe?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Here is a sample dataframe:

```
    var df = Seq(("Bob","Male","20"),("Jenn","Female","25")).toDF("Name","Gender","Age")
```

[image]

I want to change the "Age" column of the row where "Name" is equal to "Bob" to 30.

```
    var name_to_change = "Bob"
    var new_age = 30
```

How would I go about this?

Answer (score 5):

In spark you can't update a single cell. What you can do is update a column.
But using condition you can do what you want.

```
df.withColumn("Age", when(col("Name") === name_to_change, lit(new_age)).otherwise(col("Age")))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use Hive Conditional Functions and is similar to the IF statements in other programming languages

`IF(boolean testCondition, T valueTrue, T valueFalseOrNull)` inside `expr(expr: String)` function.

```
scala> df.show(false)
+----+------+---+
|Name|Gender|Age|
+----+------+---+
|Bob |Male  |20 |
|Jenn|Female|25 |
+----+------+---+


scala> df
       .withColumn("Age",expr("if((Name ='Bob'),30,Age)"))
       .show(false)

+----+------+---+
|Name|Gender|Age|
+----+------+---+
|Bob |Male  |30 |
|Jenn|Female|25 |
+----+------+---+
```